# BroadcastChannel with localStorage - compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using BroadcastChannel in my project to change all tabs titles when a new message arrived.
The problem is it only works on chrome and firefox. So I decided to create a BroadcastChannel using localStorage:

```
setInterval(function() {

    // check new messages:

    var title = localStorage.getItem('title');
    if(title != null && title != 0){

        document.title = document.title.replace(/\(\d+\)\s+/, "");
        document.title='('+title+')' + " " + document.title;

    }
    localStorage.setItem("title", "0");

    }, 100);
```

and the ajax with will check messages, if it has some new:

```
localStorage.setItem("title", i);
```

The problem is, it is working with some tabs adding (1), but some not... I think because it is reseting the localStorage setItem title = 0 before all tabs can read it. Any ideas to make it avaliable untill all tabs can read it?